# Can't import northwind sql file onto DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, import, northwind, db-browser-sqlite

I seem to get this error message.

[Error importing data: Error in statement #1: near "S":syntax error. Aborting execution and rolling back.]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzRvb.png)

I looked into the SQL file. These are the first few lines:

Select * from Shippers
/*

MS SQL Server
Setup script for SQL Practice Problems
Database: Northwind_SPP

*/

Set nocount on

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Categories]    ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categories](
...

Can't seem to find the "Syntax error" especially in line 1.

Answer (score 0):

The Northwind SQL examples are for [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server), which may have a slightly different syntax than [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite). You won't be able to use them with an RDBMS they were not intended for.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://github.com/jpwhite3/northwind-SQLite3 to download.

Started DBeaver.

Created connection to the download and :-

[image]